# How to get the exact offset included in getBoundingClientRect top and bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have an HTML that looks somewhat like this:

```
<body>
   <img src="image.svg" width="600" height="600" />
   <svg width="1500" height="650"/>
</body>
```

basically a static image SVG with height 600 is placed on top of the svg target for d3js. When I use the function `this.getBoundingClientRect()` the values for top and bottom include this 600 in them and therefore for capturing mouse events like hovering etc I have to take this offset into account. I also noticed that if I scroll down a bit in the page this offset also changes so fixing it e.g. to 600 is insufficient. Where can I get this viewport-depending offset from dynamically so it is always consistent?

```
function example(event, bounding) {
  // TODO: review this hack
  var magicYOffset = 600;

  var y = event[1];
  var top = bounding.top - magicYOffset;
  var bottom = bounding.bottom - magicYOffset;

  // TODO: do something with the new top and bottom
  return ???;
}

d3.drag()
  .on('start', function (d) {
    var event = d3.touch(this) || d3.mouse(this);
    clickX  = event[0];
    clickY  = event[1];
    cursorX = event[0];
    cursorY = event[1];

    var boundingRect = this.getBoundingClientRect();

    var flag = example(event, boundingRect);
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try getting the .offsetLeft and .offsetTop of the SVG. That should take it from the entire page, instead of the viewport, which will keep it from changing.